# Is there anyway to allow javascript without using a WebView on the iPhone?

Tags: javascript, iphone

I'm trying to make an app for a website (kind of like the facebook app). The problem is, logging in requires javascript to be enabled. I can't find anything in the documentation that refers to using javascript that isn't part of the UIWebView class.

Comment: Does the website have an API to use? It sounds like you're trying to authenticate using the same HTML form data the website uses.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm currently trying to do. I'm going to say no there's no API. It's actually my Universities website. It's horrible to navigate on the mobile browser so I thought I'd try out making an app for it.

Answer (score 0):

The company I work for has the same. You are actually approaching this the wrong way. NSURLConnection allows you to pass all the information you need to the server ie username and password. Sometimes there will be additional parameters that get submitted using Javascript. What you have to do here is scan the necessary page for this variable name, grab the variable basically using a tokenizer, then send it back to the server using NSURLConnection POST/GET or part of he URL (or whatever way its being done). Let me know if you want more details on how I do it.

Here is the chunk of code that does the NSURLConnection with Javascript values:

```
if (postData) {
        [theRequest setHTTPMethod:HTTP_METHOD_POST];
        [theRequest setValue:FORM_ENCODING forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
    }
    if(cookies)
        [theRequest setAllHTTPHeaderFields:cookies];
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest  delegate:self  startImmediately:YES];
```

the postData in mine is in he form of a string like: "username=Rudigern&password=thePassword&JSVariable=somelongtoken"

This is of course specific to the site and getting somelongtoken is done by scanning the page for JSVariable. Some websites also require cookies as well as these variables and that is done by the cookie line. theRequest is of type NSURLMutableRequest.

This is how to look for the token:

```
[scanner scanUpToString:@"JSVariable=" intoString:somelongtoken];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, it'd be really helpful to hear how you do it. I'm new to most of this stuff and kind of learning it as I go.

Comment: I've added a bit of code. There is unfortunately not much more I can add thats not specific to your case. Javascript being used for authentication is typically for automation of certain pages, submitting data or client side validation. You really have to mimic what the Javascript is doing in your own code as there is no object that complies javascript for you.

Comment: Okay so in the source code there is this:
`<input type=hidden name="TOKEN" value="DB070210142F2100RIWSVVMXBNOBTR">`
Would that be the variable I'm looking for?

Comment: probably. So the variable name is TOKEN